# VBA: Convert range to cell numbers e.g. (1,1)

Tags: excel, vba

By using this code I get a range selected in my worksheet.
E.g. "BE5:BE182" I get as a return from this code:

```
MsgBox "Selected range: " & Selection.Areas(1).Address(False, False)
```

Now I want my retrive BE5 and translate that into numeric values for both col. and row (e.g. 1,1), and I also want to do this for BE182. How do I do that?

Ambition: My goal with the macro is to select a range where numeric data should be appended. Based on the row count between start of range and end of range I will always use col 1 (A) where country name are stored. Against these I want do achive a similar VLOOKUP-function, against data from another workbook - where the user also should select a range from where data should be taken from.

The idea of letting the user define col. and row-range is that the row-range against vlook-up can change and that the col maybe not always is just +1.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You already know that the `1,1` so no reason to write code to give you that. Essentially `Selection.Cells(1,1)` refers to `BE5`. To get the size of the range you can do `Selection.Rows.Count` and `Selection.Columns.Count`. Which means that: `Selection.Cells(1,1).Offset(Selection.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count)` would get you range/cell `BE182`. I have no idea what you are trying to do though as your question isn't terribly clear.

Comment: So Selection.Cells(1,1) is BE5? I didn't understand that ^^ - thanks. But how do I 'break-down' that into a numeric value x (e.g. 48) - for BE, and y (5) for 5? I need the numericvalue of BE5 from A1 so to speak and seperately in x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Row` and `Column` properties of the range to get the numeric bounds of the range.

```
Dim Selected As String
Dim SelectedRange() As String
Dim BeginSel As String
Dim EndSel As String

' Get the range of cells selected by the user.
Selected = Selection.Areas(1).Address(False, False)
MsgBox "Selected range: " & Selected

' Split the selected range into begin and end cells.
SelectedRange = Split(Selected, ":")
BeginSel = SelectedRange(0)
EndSel = SelectedRange(1)

MsgBox "Begin Selected range: " & BeginSel
MsgBox "End Selected range: " & EndSel

' Convert the begin and end cells to row and column values
MsgBox Range(BeginSel).Row & ", " & Range(BeginSel).Column
MsgBox Range(EndSel).Row & ", " & Range(EndSel).Column
```

Here I split the selected range on the `":"` character to get the begin and end cells of the range. You'll probably want to check the length of the array returned by the `Split` function to make sure the user has selected an actual *range* of cells instead of a single cell (or nothing).

This converts the selected range `A1:E3` into the coordinates (1, 1) and (3, 5), for example.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub RowAndColumn()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, addy As String

    addy = Selection.Address(0, 0)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox Selection.Row & "," & Selection.Column
    Else
        arr = Split(addy, ":")
        Set r1 = Range(arr(0))
        Set r2 = Range(arr(1))
        MsgBox r1.Row & "," & r1.Column & vbCrLf & r2.Row & "," & r2.Column
    End If
End Sub
```